# Joint Distribution Paramters

Tags: probability

Let $Y_i$, $i = 1, \dotsc, n$ be random variables with binary values. How many parameters is needed parameterize the joint distribution $\Pr(Y_1 = y_1, \ldots, Y_n = y_n)$? What if $Y_i$ are all independent?

I am thinking that since each one has 2 possibilities and we have n of them, it should be $2^n$ different pairs. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are quite close.

In general, you need $2^n-1$ parameters. We subtract $1$ as the probability sum to $1$.

If they are independent, then you have $n$ bernoulli distribution and only $n$ parameters is needed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why we subtract 1?

Comment: Let $n=2$. If we know $P(0,0), P(0,1), P(1,0)$, we are able to compute $P(1,1)$ isn't it?

Comment: I think I"m not understanding the idea of joint distribution correctly so I am still unsure why we subtract 1. Are you saying that we only need $2^n-1$ parameters because we can always calculate the last one from the rest we have? And for the second part, why do we have a bernoulli distribution just because $Y_i$ are all independent?

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly. Because we can compute the last entry due to the sum to $1$ constraint. For the case where things are independent, $Y_i$ are bernoulli right? Each Bernoulli distribution has $1$ parameter.

Comment: I don't think I learned it yet. But does independent means it would be bernoulli?

Comment: vaguely speaking, independence means what happens to $Y_1$ doesn't affect what happens to $Y_2$ and the opposite holds to. If $Y_1$ is binary and takes value $1$ with certain probabilily. It is a Bernoulli distribution.